# Elpy and pylint: where should a pylintrc file be placed in order to customize pylint for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, pylint

I would like to remove the 80 characters per line limit when pylint is checking files in Emacs (I am using the Elpy package for Emacs). I am on Debian Wheezy, and I'm using the backported Emacs24.

I checked the docs out here regarding the `pylintrc` hierarchy: http://docs.pylint.org/run.html#command-line-options, and tried placing a `pylintrc` and a `.pylintrc` file in my working directory with no luck. I also tried putting a `.pylintrc` in my home directory, again with no effect.

I suppose the question might be asked, "what is my working directory when I call pylint from inside Emacs?". I don't have a good answer to that question...

Where should the pylint configuration file be placed? Should it be `.pylintrc` or `pylintrc`?

Comment: elpy does not use pylint by default.

Answer (score 1):

create file:

```
~/.flake8rc

[flake8] ignore = E501
#max-line-length = 160
```

AFAIK emacs flymake is using flake8 by default (?)

Comment: Where's the documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in:

```
~/.config/pylintrc
```

If the ~/.config directory doesn't exist, create it. If that doesn't work try:

```
~/.pylintrc
```

Comment: Hi xmonk -- I just wanted to note that I already tried putting it in `~/.pylintrc` (i.e. putting it in the home directory), with no luck. According to the documentation `~/.pylintrc` should be higher up on the hierarchy.

Comment: Try ~/.config/pylintrc that's where I have it and works for me.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. What does your `pylintrc` file look like? Here's mine: http://paste.debian.net/115412/

Comment: You're using Linux? I'm on OS X, and in my case ~/.config/pytlintrc works. If you are in linux, just for test purposes, put your pylintrc in /etc/pylintrc if that still doesn't work for you, try adding: export PYLINTRC=~/.pylintrc  to your .profile or .bashrc, etc.. and source it. You will need to restart emacs for this to work , if you don't want to restart emacs in the scratch buffer run the following: (setenv "PYLINTRC" (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.pylintrc"))

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `.pylintrc` wherever you like and then tell Emacs what to use with...

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/.local/bin/pylint")
        (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.emacs.d/settings/.pylintrc")))
```

I found this answer on the Emacs Stackexchange [flycheck cannot find module for pylint](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41044/flycheck-cannot-find-module-for-pylint/41048#41048) and on my system `~/.emacs.d/settings/.pylintrc` is a symlink to the rc file from work repository.

Comment: ```(setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.emacs.d/settings/.pylintrc")``` did not help python to find its path